# How to access ejabberd admin api via HTTP?

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I read about the doc https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/api/

And I wonder how can I access those API via HTTP. I tried to access but it always 404.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your ejabberd.yml you can find a configuration like this

```
- 
port: 5280
module: ejabberd_http
request_handlers:
  "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
```

Enable api and oauth,

```
- 
port: 5280
module: ejabberd_http
request_handlers:
  "/websocket": ejabberd_http_ws
  "/api": mod_http_api
  "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
```

**We are enabling api to have access from other programming languages(JSON request and response)**

**We are enabling oauth to raise an api request and get response(Without which if we access /api we will get only 401-unauthorized error)**

Once this configuration in done, give a http request in your browser. URL must be

`http://localhost:5280/oauth/authorization_token?response_type=token&client_id=Client1&scope=get_roster+connected_users`

**get_roster and connected_users are API end points**
**Clinet1 is some name that you can give**
**response_type must be always token**

Once you hit it it will render a screen as this,

[image]

Enter your admin details and click on accept

Then in the url you will find a change something like this

`http://localhost:5280/oauth/authorization_token?access_token=Ra9W9aRgeoUgIpN0P68SIGDaatDIVcgB&token_type=bearer&expires_in=3600&scope=get_roster%20connected_users&state=`

You can see a access token there copyit and do a curl to get the connected users. (Type this command in your terminal)

`curl -v POST -H "X-Admin: true" -H "Authorization: Bearer Ra9W9aRgeoUgIpN0P68SIGDaatDIVcgB" http://localhost:5280/api/connected_users -d '[]'`

You will get a Json response with all connected users.

This is how you should make API calls in ejabberd. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I need to write a back end job in PHP to register a new user from another application to ejabberd and how could I bypass the Authorization Request screen in order to achieve it through the code?

Comment: Use external authentication method and follow the [doc](https://www.ejabberd.im/check_mysql_php)

Comment: Thank you! That's what I want.

Comment: @SiruiZhuang i guess you forgot to choose this as answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

enable ejabberd_xmlrpc in ejabberd.yml file uncomment the following lines-

```
## To handle XML-RPC requests that provide admin credentials:
  ##
  ## - 
  ##   port: 4560
  ##   module: ejabberd_xmlrpc
  ##   maxsessions: 10
  ##   timeout: 5000
  ##   access_commands:
  ##     xmlrpc:
  ##       commands: all
  ##   options: []
```

All XMLRPC are send to the following URL: http://host:4560/.
[for more detail check here](https://www.ejabberd.im/ejabberd%20integration%20with%20XMLRPC%20API)

Comment: But admin API still not work. Do you have any idea how to enable the admin API by JSON?

Comment: If you can provide the steps in activating the API will be great.