# Error while configuring Ejabberd to work with Oauth2

Tags: oauth, xmpp, ejabberd

According to [THIS SO ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37112116) and [Ejabberd Oauth DOCS](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/oauth/), I have made changes to ejabberd.yml. But, every time I hit this

```
http://localhost:5280/oauth/authorization_token?response_type=token&client_id=Client1&scope=get_roster+connected_users
```

URL, I get the following error in ejabberd logs

```
[error] <0.487.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.487.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: call to undefined function ejabberd_oauth:process([<<"authorization_token">>], {request,'GET',[<<"oauth">>,<<"authorization_token">>],[{<<"response_type">>,<<"token">>},{<<"cli...">>,...},...],...})
```

I never see the screen as shown in the SO answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of ejabberd are you using ?

Comment: Ejabberd version 15.04

Comment: Version 15.04 does not have oauth feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in [ejabberd oauth documentation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/oauth/):

> OAuth support is available in ejabberd 15.09 and newest releases.

It will not work with ejabberd 15.04.